# Having trouble passing values to my object in Python. Use `self` or is there a better approach?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, self

To start, I learned Java then C, and am now delving into Python 3.6. 
I am having trouble with printing values from an object in main

Initially I started with passing values into my object `Preferences` with using `self`. I then instantiated a variable `p` from my `Preferences` object and then printed `p` in my main method. When I tried printing, none of my values that I tried setting in my methods appeared. I had more luck with this by setting values in `Preferences` with `p.size, p.preferences, etc...` because I was able to see that when printing `p` in a method, all my set values would appear.

Beneath is my code. I am reading integers from a file, and then setting my values inside of my `Preferences` object to them.

Here is the file:

```
4
1 2 3 4 
2 1 3 4
3 4 1 2
4 3 1 2 
2 1 3 4
1 2 3 4
4 3 1 2
3 4 1 2
```

And here is my code.

```
class Preferences:

    def __init__(self):
        self.preferences = []
        self.size = 0
        self.m_preferences = []
        self.f_preferences = []

    def __str__(self):
        return "Preferences object\nSize: {}\nPreferences: {}\nMale Preferences: {}\nFemale Preferences: {}".format(self.size, self.preferences, self.m_preferences, self.f_preferences)

    def get_preferences(self):
        p = Preferences()
        p.size = self.size
        p.preferences = self.preferences
        p.m_preferences = self.preferences[0: len(self.preferences)//2]
        p.f_preferences = self.preferences[len(self.preferences)//2 : len(self.preferences)]

    def read_file(self):
        p = Preferences()
        with open('input1.txt', 'r') as f:
            p.size = f.readline()
            temp_preferences = f.readlines()
            p.preferences = [x.strip().split(' ') for x in temp_preferences[0:]]
            p.get_preferences()

def main():
    p = Preferences()
    p.read_file()
    print(p)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is my attempt at passing all values in my methods using `p = Preferences()` to assign values to variables like `size, m_preferences, etc.` I expected to see

```
Preferences object
Size: 4

Preferences: [['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['2', '1', '3', '4'], ['3', '4', '1', '2'], ['4', '3', '1', '2'], ['2', '1', '3', '4'], ['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['4', '3', '1', '2'], ['3', '4', '1', '2']]
Male Preferences: [['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['2', '1', '3', '4'], ['3', '4', '1', '2'], ['4', '3', '1', '2']]
Female Preferences: [['2', '1', '3', '4'], ['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['4', '3', '1', '2'], ['3', '4', '1', '2']]`
```

But Instead I get empty values of these values being:

```
Preferences object
Size: 0
Preferences: []
Male Preferences: []
Female Preferences: []`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are instantiating new Preference object inside `read_file` and `get_preferences`.

The fixed code will look like

```
class Preferences:

    def __init__(self):
        self.preferences = []
        self.size = 0
        self.m_preferences = []
        self.f_preferences = []

    def __str__(self):
        return "Preferences object\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}".format(self.size, self.preferences, self.m_preferences, self.f_preferences)

    def get_preferences(self):
        self.m_preferences = self.preferences[0: len(self.preferences)//2]
        self.f_preferences = self.preferences[len(self.preferences)//2 : len(self.preferences)]

    def read_file(self):
        with open('input1.txt', 'r') as f:
            self.size = f.readline()
            temp_preferences = f.readlines()
            self.preferences = [x.strip().split(' ') for x in temp_preferences[0:]]
            self.get_preferences()

def main():
    p = Preferences()
    p.read_file()
    print(p)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And the output:

```
python3 t.py
Preferences object
4

[['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['2', '1', '3', '4'], ['3', '4', '1', '2'], ['4', '3', '1', '2'], ['2', '1', '3', '4'], ['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['4', '3', '1', '2'], ['3', '4', '1', '2']]
[['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['2', '1', '3', '4'], ['3', '4', '1', '2'], ['4', '3', '1', '2']]
[['2', '1', '3', '4'], ['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['4', '3', '1', '2'], ['3', '4', '1', '2']]
```

Comment: Wow I swear I tried this earlier. I guess I was mixing up `p` and `self` a lot. Thank you this works.